# CV/Résumé - Article Drop

Tags: articles, formality, zero-article, headline-english

I think my question is rather a stylistic one, but it really bugs me.

From a grammatical standpoint, "the" should always precede ordinal numbers. However, articles are usually omitted in headlines. So I am asking if it is appropriate to strike off articles from a résumé or cv.

In other words, should I write "The 5th Conference on Machine Learning" or just "5th Conference on Machine Learning" as a heading/subheading under the experience section of my résumé/cv?

Comment: Well I would go for however the conference call themselves on their website. If in doubt though, I'd put a full title in my CV

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey For future reference then, should I capitalize the article in your title?  That is *the Grey* or *The Grey*?

Comment: @deadrat very good question, I don't know myself, I'd capitalise just so that it is clearer when one writes it out without spaces. However, [Gandalf](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandalf) the Grey is written without a capital so perhaps if you're adding spaces don't. But really, I don't know!

Answer (score 2):

For proper names, include any articles that are actually present. In your example, include "The." My feeling why this is the case is if the person reading the resume knows the reference, it will resonate better if it's the name they're used to. It may sound awkward to the reader if abbreviated, defeating the whole purpose for putting it there in the first place.

For common names, I'd leave it out under most circumstances to save on word count.

Answer (score 1):

In the CV context - Bullet form is the accepted norm.

You don't need complete sentences... the objective is to communicate as much info as possible with the fewest words. In this case "The" adds zero value... the same information is conveyed without it.  Lose the "the".

Do you even need the "5th"? - did you host this conference, participate in it, attend?  Does the 5th event have any special significance over 1 thru 4. If not drop that too!

Without more context, I'd consider simply:  Machine Learning Conference

Comment: This is a stylistic consideration. Generally, you should use the names people give themselves (or their ventures), and if that includes an otherwise-superfluous article, then so be it. Assuming the conference is significant in the V of the owner of the CV, identifying which conference is important since it allows anyone interested to check.